# MySql give error Table doesn't exist But it does

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have just copied the mysql db files from another xamp the same latest version.
When running mysql query in phpmyadmin get the below this error:[image]

Comment: Have u checked the DB which you are pointing ?

Comment: Maybe a permission problem. How has you copied the db?

Comment: maybe table missing some data format so that table not complete.

Answer (score 0):

This is engine problem.You should change the engine to MyISAM or drop and create again by

```
1.show create table table_name;
2.insert into table_name select * from oldtable_name.
```